# Is Utils file good practice?

Tags: java, c#, c++

I saw lots of projects that use that kind of file. It usually contains functions that are required from lots of places in the code. It seems logicality to save code from the number of classes and namespaces that contain one or two functions. But on the other hand it makes code less separated into logical parts that can make harder understanding of structure of project. So what is my question about. Is it good or bad to have such file in project?

The language I use is c++ but it seems the question refers to any programming language.

Comment: I think this question is a little too broad, but I think it is common practice to make a library from your own code and use it in a bunch of projects. Remember that a part of object oriented code is reusing what you have already written.

Comment: This was a lot more common before extension methods existed but (and this is an opinion) now that we can write extension methods, Utility classes are giving way to static extension classes for specific purposes.

Comment: I believe util classes are fine. Would you rather there be a lot of duplicate code? No. It also makes a smaller code base. And you shouldn't have an issue reading the code if it is well written and/or commented appropriately.

Answer (score 10):

Whether or not a utils file is bad practice depends on many factors.
Other factors are (and the list is not exhaustive and likely subject to opinions of different individuals):

- Does it contain functions that logically belong together. Or are there functions in there that don't. The latter is bad practice of course.
- Is it part of a well named namespace to make clear what the purpose of the utils is.
- alongside with the namespace structure is the also the directory structure
- unit tests that show how the utils are working and how the api is supposed to be used by users.
- if you can find a better name than simply utils, by all means do.
- these utils file can show up in many forms, service is just as good.
- Well named classes and function names, variables , ...

Conclusion: if it is good or bad heavily depends on the broader context and on the content of the file in question. The rules of clean code always apply. The idea of putting utility functions in separate files is common practice, but they are only useful if they are structured very well so people find their way to them, and in them easily. If this is OK, people will use them. Otherwise people will not use them, and you will still end up with many util files that still contain a lot of duplication with slightly varying implementations.